# Get the item with the biggest value in a Bag collection in Raku

Tags: raku

```
my $coll=bag <1 2 2 3 2 4 4 2 2>;
say $coll; # => Bag(1, 2(5), 3, 4(2))
```

How to get the item (key) with the biggest value, i.e. the `2(5)` from this Bag collection?

(Optional) Is there a way to tell the Bag to count only those elements which are successive and disregard all which are not successive so that the result would be `Bag(2(4), 4(2))` ?

Comment: "disregard all which are not successive" ... .oO ( only keep a value if it's the same as either the one before or the one after ) ... `<1 2 2 3 2 4 4 2 2> .rotor(3=>-2, :partial) .map: { .[1] if .[1] === .[0] | .[2] }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your first question, there's a method for that:

```
say $coll.maxpairs; # 2 => 5
```

To answer your second question: no, you cannot.  You can only devise some logic that will pre-process the values before getting to the `Bag`.

```
 <1 2 2 3 2 4 4 2 2>.map( *somelogic* ).Bag
```

Leaving the *somelogic* part as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Having concentrated on the use of `Bag` I haven't come across the `maxpairs` method. It turns out that it's a general method which applies to any associative-like list. Didn't know it. Good to know.

Comment: Perhaps that's worthy of a doc issue  :-)